# subdomain redirection to specific folder in jetty configuration

Tags: dns, jetty, office365, redirect, cname

I have a primary domain: domain.com.
At host level, I have jetty running.
I would like to do the following.

STEP 1. subdomain.domain.com CNAME to domain.com/subdomain
Learnt it could not be done so I had to set up
subdomain.domain.com CNAME to domain.com (as temporary fix under the condition that I manage step 2 hereafter)

STEP 2. configure jetty so that all requests coming from subdomain.domain.com are redirected to $JETTY_HOME/subdomain

I would like to know if this can be done. And some guidance to configure STEP 2 mostly. Which file to configure and how to set up rule (I am new to jetty environment).

Thanks

Comment: "redirected to $JETTY_HOME/subdomain" makes no sense (or do you really want 2 separate jetty servers each with their own instance configuration?).  Or are you wanting perhaps to have a redirect of `http://subdomain.domain.com/` to `http://domain.com/subdomain/`?

Comment: Hi Joakim. Thanks for your reply. Yes that is exactly what I want to do: redirect subdomain.domain.com to domain.com/subdomain. In this case, DNS is delegated to Office 365. Where I am able through DNS settings of domain.com: a CNAME record that will send any request to subdomain.domain.com to domain.com. I believe that it is now on web server (jetty), that I need to create rule to detect all queries coming from subdomain.domain.com and redirect to correct subfolder. Please correct me if I'm wrong on this. I'm new to both DNS & Jetty.